# Bash Prompt using if [ $? = 0 ]; then; else and /$ doesn't work the way it's meant

Tags: bash, command-prompt

I know I already had this running quite some time ago, but I haven't messed around with scripts and bash prompts for a long time an I am unable to come up with a solution.

I tried to use if [ $? = 0 ]; then; else;, in order to become a different prompt if a command provides an error and \$, in order to get a #, in case root is logged in. I even came up with this nonsensical long prompt command:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [ $? = 0 ]; then PS1="\[\e[31m\]║\[\033[04;35m\]\$(/bin/date)\[\e[00;32m\] History: \! \[\e[31m\]Jobs: \j \[\e[34m\]Status: \[\e[32m\]▇▇  ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\n\[\033[31m\]║\[\e[33m\]\u@\[\e[37m\]\w/\[\e[32m\]\$:\[\e[0m\]"; else PS1="\[\e[31m\]║\[\033[04;35m\]\$(/bin/date)\[\e[00;32m\] History: \! \[\e[31m\]Jobs: \j \[\e[34m\]Status: \[\e[31m\]▇▇ ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\n\[\e[31m\]║\[\e[33m\]\u@\[\e[37m\]\w/\[\e[32m\]\$:\[\e[0m\]"; fi'
```

I know the problem is that the if [ $? = 0 ]; then; else; portion works between "", while the /$ seems to work only between ''.

The funny thing is that this works ...

```
PS1="\`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \[\e[33m\]^_^\[\e[0m\]; else echo \[\e[31m\]O_O\[\e[0m\]; fi\`[\u@\h:\w]\\$ "
```

while this doesn't (the if [ \$? = 0 ]; then; else;) (\$(/bin/date) and \$ works this way)

```
PS1="\[\033[31m\]║\[\033[04;35m\]\$(/bin/date)\[\033[00;32m\] History: \! \[\033[31m\]Jobs: \j \`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \[\e[34m\]Status: \[\e[32m\]▇▇; else echo \[\e[34m\]Status: \[\e[31m\]▇▇; fi\` ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\n\[\033[31m\]║\[\033[33m\]\u@\[\033[37m\]\w/\[\033[32m\]\\$:\[\033[0m\]"
```

I'd like to keep both in my prompt, but I am obviously missing something (maybe because I was looking at this prompt too much. I would be glad to have a prompt that features \$ and \$(/bin/date), while changing if an error occurs, please help.

Cheers.

Comment: You can replace the call to `/bin/date` with `\D{%+}`.

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and just write a function that does what you want, and then have PROMPT_COMMAND call it.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend building your prompt from `PROMPT_COMMAND`, rather than trying to cram executable code into the value of `PS1` itself. This makes the quoting simpler, as well as breaking the prompt into manageable pieces.

```
prompt_cmd () {
  exit_status=$?
  PS1='\[\e[31m\]║\[\e[04;35m\]\D{%+}'
  PS1+=' \[\e[32m\]History: \!'
  PS1+=' \[\e[31m\]Jobs: \j'
  PS1+=' \[\e[34m\]Status: '
  if [[ $exit_status = 0 ]]; then
    PS1+='\[\e[32m\]'
  else
    PS1+='\[\e[31m\]'
  fi
  PS1+='▇▇ '"${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}"'\n'
  PS1+='\[\e[31m\]║\[\e[33m\]\u@\[\e[37m\]\w\[\e[32m\]\$:\[\e[0m\]'
}

PROMPT_COMMAND='prompt_cmd'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a nice way to solve this issue (except that \D{%+} doesn't work, it only returns "%+" sorry that I forgot to mention this point, that was the main point that made me use "\$(/bin/date)".

Comment: Oh, I see the `%+` appears to be a non-standard extension to what `strftime` might accept.

Comment: I solved it by using "" while falling back to /bin/date on the base definition of PS1 (and I placed a reset to get rid of the underline after the date call) .. works really nicely now. Thanks a lot, you saved my day. I know I once had it pressed in one line of PS1, but I am done with prompt hassles for the next couple of weeks. PS1="\[\e[31m\]║\[\e[04;35m\]\$(/bin/date)\[\033[0m\]"

Comment: I'd still like to know a little more about the "quote and backtick issue". I think I might have forgotten something vital here. So .. what is the difference between stuff in quotes and stuff in backticks?